# How to use connect-flash with ejs in express 4.x

Tags: node.js, ejs, connect-flash

I have a project that I need to use [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash#readme), I am using view engine as ejs. Even I configure everything fine, in my opinion, connect-flash doesn't work. Could anybody please help me abput that?

**Here how did I define the session, connect-flash and global variables:**

```
app.use(cookieParser());
//Express session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

//Connect flash middleware
app.use(flash());

//Global varibales
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    next();
});
```

**Here is the export module get function:**

```
module.exports.xxx_index_get = function(req, res) {
xxx.findOne({
    id: 'xxx'
}).then(xxx=> {
    req.flash('success', 'user succesfulyl registered')
    res.render('xxx/xxx', {
        xxx
    });
});};
```

**And here is the ejs file:**

```
<% if(success.length > 0) { %><div class="alert alert-success">
<%= success %>    </div><% } %>
```

I would be really thankful If somebody will help about that. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please add your error.

Comment: There is no error thats the problem...

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have required all the essential details for flash.

Include below code into you routes

```
module.exports.xxx_index_get = function(req, res) {
xxx.findOne({
    id: 'xxx'
}).then(xxx=> {
    req.flash('success', 'user succesfulyl registered')
res.locals.message = req.flash();
    res.render('xxx/xxx', {
        xxx
    });
});};
```

and then in you views try to use something like this

```
<% if(locals.message){ %>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <strong>Well done!</strong> <%=message.success%>
    </div>
    <% } %>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution

```
//middlewares/flashMessage.js
exports.flashMessage = function (req, res, next) {
    const successFlashMessageArr = req.flash('success');
    const errorFlashMessageArr = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.successFlashMessage = successFlashMessageArr[0];
    res.locals.errorFlashMessage = errorFlashMessageArr[0];
    next();
}
```

In app.js use this middleware

```
const flashMessageMiddleware = require('./middlewares/flashMessage');
app.use(flashMessageMiddleware.flashMessage);
```

And in the EJS file, you can use global variables

```
<% if(successFlashMessage){ %>
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <%=successFlashMessage%>
</div>
<% } %>

<% if(errorFlashMessage){ %>
<div class="alert alert-error">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <%=errorFlashMessage%>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Your middleware saved my day. Thanks. 

Answer (score 2):

You can use the example of Daud Khan, however, when declaring messages it is out of scope, to display your messages use `<%- %>`

example of how your message will look:

```
<% if(successFlashMessage){ %>
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <%- successFlashMessage %>
</div>
<% } %>

<% if(errorFlashMessage){ %>
<div class="alert alert-error">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <%- errorFlashMessage %>
</div>
<% } %>
```